# How does concurrent processing really speed things up?

Tags: concurrency, cpu

Assume CPU has only single core, is context switching / concurrent processing of any real value?

Eg: If I have 2 video's being played, each of 5 mins, then with concurrency each video should take take 10 mins not five, since CPU flipped between video 1 and video 2 in concurrent processing?

Comment: Well, in regard to your video example, we can think of an easy counterexample: Imagine a frame rate of 60 fps. This means we only switch frames 60 times per second. Most of that time, the CPU will be idle (if these are the only processes running). So you wouldn't really need the 10 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to describe concurrent processing is *timesharing*. The single core works on one program for a very short amount of time, then switches to the other process. So, if one process uses up all the power of that single core, and you start two of them, they will run at half the speed of just running one.

**The slowdown is only visible if a single instance of the process requires more than half of the CPU power.** And your video example doesn't. The speed of the video playing is usually dependent dependent on the video *framerate*. That framerate is usually about 30-60 FPS. That slow framerate gives the CPU plenty of time to show the frame on the other video. The problem of concurrency would be much more visible if the process was CPU intensive, like Minecraft.